# NSDecimalNumber to double. What is the correct way to do this in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've been searching for a clean and correct way to convert an `NSDecimalNumber` retrieved from `CoreData` to a Double.

I'm looking for a recommendation on how to do this. I need to take 2 decimal numbers from my `CoreData` and calculate a percentage to use in a progress bar etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

NSDecimalNumber has a property `var doubleValue: Double { get }`. So you can say `num.doubleValue`.

For division of two NSDecimalNumbers you should use `num1.dividing(by: num2)`.

Keep in mind that in Swift you can also use [`Decimal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal) which supports `+`, `*`, `/`, etc.